# Truncate tail of NSTextField fails only in OSX 10.8

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nssplitview

I am using an `NSTextField` with following settings/properties as shown in the image

[image]

[image]

It works abnormally. At times when it is truncating the text while sometime it doesn't as shown :

[image]

[image]

I am unable to find the issue.

The complete implementation is like this : I have an `NSSplitView` on the one side I have put the textfield.

Please give some ideas and help me out to resolve this issue.